# Would a train of objects revolving in a ring orbit generate gravitational wave vortex?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, gravity, waves, gravitational-waves

If the objects have quadrupole moment and are rotating around a ring, would they generate gravitational vortex inside the ring?

Comment: Just out of curiosity  could you give a source for the gravitational vortex?

Comment: Just curiosity. If not a vortex then maybe a spiral wave?

Comment: Can you help?@Otto

Comment: Cheers; I actually asked about the vortex since I dont know what exactly is a gravitational vortex Ive done a bit of calculations with gwaves

Comment: http://www.thenakedscientists.com/forum/index.php?topic=42033.0